# How do I do this? (Can't think of an accurate title) (PYTHON)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a text-based choose your own adventure game.

In this game, there are three options per turn: to scavenge, to rest, and to continue on your journey. Each time choose 'continue on your journey' the Area variable moves up one. If you scavenge twice in the same area, I want it to say "You couldn't find anything.". But If i have to write 'if Area == one and Canteen == 1:
print"You couldn't find anything." (canteen is the item you get for scavenging in the first area) If I have to write that for every option, I will get very frustrated. So what is the way to easily test if they've scavenged in that area, and say "You couldn't find anything." Thanks in advance!"

Comment: Consider classes, dictionaries, state variables....

Comment: Google "state transition table".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for something really simple, this could serve as an example:

```
area = 0
inventory = []
area_scavenged = False

while True:
    print 'Area: %s\nInventory: %s' % (area, str(inventory))
    choice = raw_input("Choose an option: ")
    if choice == 'rest':
        pass
    elif choice == 'continue':
        area_scavenged = False
        area += 1
    elif choice == 'scavenge':
        if not area_scavenged:
            # Append to inventory the item that corresponds to the area you're in
            inventory.append('whatever')
            area_scavenged = True
        else:
            print("You couldn't find anything")
    elif choice == 'end':
        break
```